# Add an exception to .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I added the folowing code to main .htaccess

```
# BEGIN
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+/?$ /$1/? [L,R=301]
# END
```

I'd like to add an exception to any link ended with .../page/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If all you need is to exclude requests with `/page` in the URI-path, you may try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+/?$ /$1/? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want your rules to apply under certain conditions, you can use `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /.*/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+/?$ /$1/? [L,R=301]
```